# Integral of fundamental solution to Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

On PDE Evans, 2nd edition, page 46, it says the following:

> **LEMMA** (Integral of fundamental solution). For each time $t > 0$,
>   \begin{align}
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x,t) \, dx = 1
> \end{align}

Note that 
\begin{align}
\Phi(x,t) :=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^\frac{n}{2}} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}} \, \, (x \in \mathbb{R}^n, t > 0) \\
0 \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, (x \in \mathbb{R}^n, t > 0)
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The following is Evan's proof, as printed exactly in the textbook:

> **Proof.** We calculate
>   \begin{align}
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x,t) \, dx &= \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^\frac{n}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}} \, dx \\
> &= \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|z|^2}\, dx \\
> &= \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-z_i^2} \, dz_i \\
> &= 1
> \end{align}

What I do not understand from the above proof are from step 1 to step 2, where u-substitution is employed. When I tried this (as in, let $z = \frac{x}{(4t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$), I got:
\begin{align}
|z|^2 = \frac{|x|^2}{4t} \text{ and } dz = \frac{1}{(4t)^{\frac{1}{2}}} dx
\end{align}

which means

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x,t) \, dx &= \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^\frac{n}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{(\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}(4t)^\frac{n-1}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}} \frac{1}{(4t)^\frac{1}{2}} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{(\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}(4t)^\frac{n-1}{2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|z|^2} \, dz \\
&\not= \frac{1}{(\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|z|^2} \, dz \\
&= 1
\end{align}

I do not understand why my proof does not match the proof printed in the Evans textbook.

Comment: You're dividing each of the $n$ coordinates by $\sqrt{4t}$, so the determinant of the transformation is $\dfrac{1}{(\sqrt{4t})^n}$.